# Bridge unsuccessfully destroyed in "A Bridge Too Far"

Tags: a-bridge-too-far

In "A Bridge Too Far", the Germans try to blow up a bridge but fail. Was that bridge "Nijmegen bridge" or which bridge was it? I had heard if the Germans had succeeded in blowing it up, the war would have been prolonged, so ideally I am trying to find out the bridge’s name.

Answer (score 2):

The forward action in "A Bridge too Far" was centered around the "John Frost Bridge," though there was another small bridge and a railway bridge nearby. It was then known as the "Arnhem road bridge." The Allies failed to gain control of the bridge and eventually destroyed it themselves in an air raid a few weeks later to keep German tanks from heading south again.

In the movie, the bridge that the Germans tried to destroy was the "Nijmegen railway bridge." The Allies did succeed in taking the bridge and defusing the explosives, but German special forces frogmen managed to destroy it in late September, just a week after the Allies captured it.

The failure of Market Garden meant that the Allies were not able to cross the Rhine in force until they were able to capture the road bridge at Remagen in March 1945.

[Info about the John Frost Bridge at Nijmegen »](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Frost_Bridge)

[Info about the Nijmegen railway bridge »](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nijmegen_railway_bridge)

Comment: John Frost ("the Fohn Frost Bridge") is/was Colonel Frost, played in the Feature Motion Picture "A Bridge Too Far" by Anthony Hopkins. It was not known as the "John Frost Bridge" during WWII, because it was named after him, yet.

Answer (score 2):

[image: John Frost brug]

Living in Arnhem since 2012 I would like to correct that the John Frost bridge is actually located in **Arnhem**, connecting the southern and northern parts that are divided by the river Rhine. Back in the war it was still called the  Arnhem road bridge and has been renamed after the British major-general who led the defense of the bridge in 1944, as shown in 'A Bridge Too Far'. It was actually destroyed twice, first to slow down the German invasion in 1940. In 1944, after its defense, it actually was bombarded by the Allies to prevent Germans sending reinforcements down to the southern part.

The railway bridge however is located in Nijmegen, indeed. Arnhem and Nijmegen are located 30 kilometres apart from one another and were important strategical points in the war, especially surrounding Operation Market Garden, to help make way for the Allies coming from Belgium towards the south of Netherlands. [image]